# Fetch API Url with Arguments

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I have this [working] HTML/Javascript code to fetch data from a json API.

```
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

fetch('https://api-url.tld')
.then(res => res.json()
.then(json => {
  getElement('total_clicks').innerText = json["stats"]["total_clicks"];
}));
```

But now I want to use a different API, with different requirements. I can retrieve the json output with the following curl command:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://api-url.tld' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-Api-Key: APIKEY'
```

This is an example output of it:

```
{
  "visits": {
    "nonOrphanVisits": {
      "total": 0,
      "nonBots": 0,
      "bots": 0
    },
    "data": 0,
  }
}
```

What should the first code look like so that I get the same result? At the end of `"nonOrphanVisits" -> "total": 0` should be inserted here in `getElement('total_clicks').innerText`.

**Or in short:** The question is how to fetch an api in html with arguments, here for example "X-API-KEY".

Thank you for Answers!

Comment: Use `json.visits.nonOrphanVisits.total`

Comment: What's so different from the response in the first API that you don't understand how to access it?

Comment: There are no arguments in the second API call.

Comment: @Barmar
The question is rather how do I make an api fetch in html with arguments, here for example "X-API-Key".

Comment: That's not an argument, it's a header. I've replaced the dup with one that shows how to send headers with Fetch.